# Strong relative boundedness argument for the annihilation operator

Tags: operator-theory

Could someone please explain to me how to prove that the creation operator $a^*=-\frac{d}{dx} +x$ is the adjoint of the annihilation operator $a=\frac{d}{dx} + x$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

I would guess a strong relative boundedness argument is needed (i.e. relative bound smaller than one), but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I do not see the need here for that argument. Actually, I do not see how you would get there. Where do you see here relatively bounded perturbations?

Comment: In order to use the following:
Let $T$ be closed and densely defined. Suppose $S$ and $S^*$ are strongly dominated by $T$ and $T^*$ respectively. Then $D((T+S)^*) = D(T^*)$ and $(T+S)^*=T+S$ (see Birman & Solomjak, chapter 3). Here, strong domination is $T$-boundedness with relative bound smaller than one.

Comment: 1. You would like to use a heavy machinery for an easy problem. 2. I do not see how you would like to use this here? My question was not what the theorem is (that was somehow clear), but how you would like to use it.